# it was only recently that

Tags: sentence-construction

> It was only recently that we've begun to discover the answer.
>
> It was only recently that he got well.

1. What is 'that' indicating, or modifying in the both sentences?
   I think it is indicating, or modifying 'only recently'.
2. Can 'that' be substituted with 'when' ?
3. if written as 'That he got well was only recently', it does not make sense?
   I think it is grammatically correct, though it reads odd.

Comment: The subordinator "that" is a marker introducing the declarative content clauses "that we've begun to discover the answer / that he got well" functioning as complement (not modifier) of "recently". No, "when" cannot replace "that", and your last example is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Then, it would be better to regard "that we've begun to discover the answer." clause as 'it' ?

Comment: No, in extraposition constructions, "it" is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. The extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP. But extraposition is not possible here, anyway.

Comment: Note that your sentence would be better rendered with time agreement: "It **is** only recently that **we've begun**" or "It **was** only recently that **we began**" ...

Comment: @Robusto not just better rendered; it's nonsensical as it is. *It was ... we began* or *It is ... we have begun*.

Comment: Also, *It was only recently that he recovered* ;o) but *got* isn't wrong like the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I'm going to go with the expert's definition and just copy BillJ's comments:

> The subordinator "that" is a marker introducing the declarative content clauses "that we've begun to discover the answer / that he got well" functioning as complement (not modifier) of "recently".
>
> ... in extraposition constructions, "it" is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. The extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP. But extraposition is not possible here

FYI:

> **Extraposition**:  The placing of a word or group of words outside or at the end of a clause, while retaining the sense. The subject is often postponed and replaced by it at the start, as in *it's no use crying over spilt milk* rather than *crying over spilt milk is no use*.

(2) It is not possible to substitute "when" for "that" to mark the declarative content, but it is possible to use it to define the time frame.

> It was only recently, **when technological advances allowed the creation of new, more powerful investigative tools**, that we've begun to discover the answer

(3) "That he got well was only recently" is not grammatically correct. Instead make it a simple declarative sentence:

> He got well only recently.